# What plugins improve Google Chrome as a web developer's browser?

Tags: google-chrome

The usual recommendations for a web development and debugging web browser are Firefox/Firebug or Safari/Web Inspector.

But I like Google Chrome, and would like to use this as my primary development browser. What plugins or tools should I get to optimise my web programming experience with Chrome?

Comment: It contains the same tools as Safari web inspector

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's own "Firebug" is very good, just right click and inspect element to bring it up.

[Frame two pages](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) is helpful.

[Chris Pederick's Web Developer toolbar](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/eldgpcphflnopbjadiaonofideekgdgm) is good too.

Answer (score 0):

The [Development and Coding Search](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/references/development-search) ([Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ooehfcnceghcfhnilipfdmfoiaahmopc)) is one of many Chrome  extensions for developers. See the [featured web development extensions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/featured/web_dev) for more developer-friendly extensions.

Answer (score 0):

[Pendule](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi) has a lot of good bits and bobs under one extension/icon. Few things I like about it...

- View generated source
- Colour picker
- Ruler
- Validator

There are probably tons of alternatives, but it's the best I've seen so far.